# The progress view bar does not update/grow in a quiz app

Tags: ios, swift

When you give the correct answer in a multiple choice test, a question number, score points update/increase, but the progress bar does not, it remains the same, not changing.

Below is the code, which separates the width of the screen/view into equal parts depending on the number of questions. I found it earlier in YouTube, and it worked on the project/app shown there. But I cannot apply it in my case and I don’t know why.  *progressView.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width / CGFloat(questions.count)) * CGFloat(questionNumber)*

I have some yellow alert notifications in main.storyboard, but I think it should not cause this problem.

```
@IBOutlet weak var questionCounterLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet private var questionNumberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private var questionNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private var tableView: UITableView!


private func shuffleQuestions() {
  shuffledQuestions = questions.shuffled()
  questionNumber = 1
  score = 0
  showQuestion()
}

private func showQuestion() {
  questionCounterLabel.text = "\(questionNumber)/\(questions.count)"
  scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
  
  currentQuestion = shuffledQuestions[questionNumber - 1]
  questionNameLabel.text = currentQuestion?.text ?? ""
  
  questionNumberLabel.text = "Question \(questionNumber)"
  questionNumber += 1
  score += 1
  progressView.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width / CGFloat(questions.count)) * CGFloat(questionNumber)

  tableView.reloadData()
}

private func checkAnswer(for answer: Answer) {
  if answer.correct {
    if questionNumber > questions.count {
      scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Awesome",
                                          message: "End of Quiz. Do you want to start over?",
                                          preferredStyle: .alert)
            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart",
                                              style: .default,
                                              handler: { action in self.shuffleQuestions() } )
            alert.addAction(restartAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
      return
    }
    showQuestion()
  } else {
    // wrong
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong",
                                  message: "You failed",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss",
                                  style: .cancel,
                                  handler: nil))
    present(alert, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changes to the UI should always occur on the main/foreground thread, in this case it's happening on a background queue. Use:

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.progressView.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width / CGFloat(questions.count)) * CGFloat(questionNumber)
}
```

**Update:**

```
DispatchQueue.global(priority: .default).async {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.progressView.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width / CGFloat(questions.count)) * CGFloat(questionNumber)
   }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. and to add to this: it is actually very bad practice to *not* update UI components on the main thread due to speed performance issues. Users especially these days will not tolerate waiting for things to load. When you put it on the background threads you are giving the UI update a low priority which runs this risk.

Comment: Do I have to put it just inside the above mentioned function _private func showQuestion()_? Because if I leave it there, the program only asks me to add self  to make use of self semantic explicit in closures. But the progress bar still does not work, it does not grow.

Comment: @AminRezaew, how did you define it was on the background queue? As far as I understand from this printscreen all these changes happen on the main queue already. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ii__ozsaJQycw4Yppr7COES64iFgvTvU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Parfen yes put it in your function

Comment: @AminRezaew, as I mentioned above, I put it into my function, but sadly it doesn't work, the progress view bar is not growing at all.

Comment: @Parfen i updated my answer... try that and tell me that's work or no

Comment: @AminRezaew, sorry for not responding to you for so long. Fell out for several days. I 've just checked the new version of yours. Nothing changes, it still doesn't work. Moreover two yellow warning show up "'global(priority:)' was deprecated in iOS 8.0" and "'default' was deprecated in iOS 8.0: Use qos attributes instead".